# Find length of intersection between 2 points and a sphere

Tags: geometry

I have a sphere and 2 points. The points have (x,y,z) coordinates and the sphere is defined by its centre (0,0,0) and radius R. I am trying to find the length between the 2 points which intersects the sphere. How can I obtain the equation to describe this length?

See below, my objective is Length, L:

[image]

Comment: **Line** is the word that's missing here. Find the equation of your line, then find where it intersects the sphere (that would require solving a quadratic equation), then find the length.

Answer (score 1):

The sphere is: $ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 =R^2 $ .
 The line is: 
$ x=x \\ y=x\cdot\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1} -\frac{x_1(y_2-y_1)}{x_2-x_1} +y_1 =:r_yx+y_0 \\ z=x\cdot\frac{ z_2-z_1 }{x_2-x_1} -\frac{x_1(z_2-z_1)}{x_2-x_1} +z_1  =:r_zx+z_0$.
Sphere and line intersect when:
$ x^2 + (r_yx+y_0)^2 + (r_zx+z_0)^2 =R^2 \implies \\
x^2\cdot(1+r_y^2+ r_z^2) + x\cdot(2r_yy_0+2r_zz_0)+(y_0^2+z_0^2-R^2)=0\\
\\
 $
Solving for $x$ :
$$
x=\frac{ -(2r_yy_0+2r_zz_0) \pm \sqrt{(2r_yy_0+2r_zz_0)^2-4(1+r_y^2+ r_z^2)(y_0^2+z_0^2-R^2)}}{2(1+r_y^2+ r_z^2)}
$$
So for the intersection:
$$
(\Delta x)^2 = \frac{(2r_yy_0+2r_zz_0)^2-4(1+r_y^2+ r_z^2)(y_0^2+z_0^2-R^2)}{(1+r_y^2+ r_z^2)^2} \\
(\Delta y)^2 =(\Delta x)^2(\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1})^2\\
(\Delta z)^2 =(\Delta x)^2(\frac{z_2-z_1}{x_2-x_1})^2\\
$$
Length of the line segment is:
$$
\Delta x \cdot \sqrt{1 +(\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1})^2 + (\frac{z_2-z_1}{x_2-x_1})^2} = \\
\sqrt{ \frac{(2r_yy_0+2r_zz_0)^2-4(1+r_y^2+ r_z^2)(y_0^2+z_0^2-R^2)}{(1+r_y^2+ r_z^2)^2}}\cdot\sqrt{1 +r_y^2 + r_z^2}=
$$

> $$
> 2\cdot\sqrt{ \frac{(r_yy_0+r_zz_0)^2-(1+r_y^2+ r_z^2)(y_0^2+z_0^2-R^2)}{(1+r_y^2+ r_z^2)}}
> $$

Answer (score 0):

Let's call the given two points (vectors) as
$$
P_{\,1}  = \left( {x_{\,1} ,y_{\,1} ,z_{\,1} } \right)\quad P_{\,2}  = \left( {x_{\,1} ,y_{\,1} ,z_{\,1} } \right)
$$
then a generic point $P$ on the line connecting the two points will be given by
$$
P \in \overline {P_{\,1} P_{\,2} } \quad  \Rightarrow \quad P = t\,P_{\,1}  + \left( {1 - t} \right)P_{\,2} 
$$
and when $0 \leqslant t \leqslant 1$ the point will be internal to segment, and otherwise external.
The squared modulus of $P$ represents the square of its distance from origin and is given by the dot product by itself:
$$
\left| P \right|^{\,2}  = P \cdot P = t^{\,2} \,P_{\,1}  \cdot P_{\,1}  + \left( {1 - t} \right)^{\,2} P_{\,2}  \cdot P_{\,2}  + 2t\left( {1 - t} \right)P_{\,2}  \cdot P_{\,1} 
$$
The various dot products are scalars, and quite simple to calculate, and you have a simple quadratic equation.

From here you can follow two possible approaches:

1. *Find the points and then their distance*
   The point $P$ is constrained on the line, then to constained it to lie on the sphere, just equate $\left| P \right|^{\,2} $  to $R^2$, and solve for $t$.
   The values obtained will tell you whether the points are internal/external to the segment.
   The two intersection points will then be
   $$
   P_{a,\,b}  = t_{a,\,b}  \,P_{\,1}  + \left( {1 - t_{a,\,b}  } \right)P_{\,2} 
   $$
   and distance will follow obviously.
2. *Find the distance and then the points*
   Since your objective is the length of the segment, then you can more quickly
   derive the expression of $\left| P \right|^{\,2}$ with respect to $t$ and find the value $t_0$
   that minimize it.
   $$
   \begin{gathered}
     0 = \frac{d}
   {{dt}}\left| P \right|^{\,2}  = 2P_{\,1}  \cdot P_{\,1} \;t - 2\left( {1 - t} \right)P_{\,2}  \cdot P_{\,2}  + \left( {2 - 4t} \right)P_{\,2} P_{\,1}  \hfill \\
      \Rightarrow \left( {P_{\,1}  \cdot P_{\,1}  + P_{\,2}  \cdot P_{\,2}  - 2P_{\,2} P_{\,1} } \right)\;t - P_{\,2}  \cdot P_{\,2}  + P_{\,2} P_{\,1}  = 0 \hfill \\ 
   \end{gathered} 
   $$
   This will correspond to the point on the segment which is closest to the origin. Therefore
   $$
   R^{\,2}  - \left| P \right|^{\,2} (t_{\,0} ) = \left( {L/2} \right)^{\,2} 
   $$
   and you can bypass solving the quadratic equation.
   Then to find the points of intersection, if you need them, consider that $t$ as defined above is the measure
   of the relative distance (i.e. "with sign") of the point $P$ from $P1$ along the line, in the direction from $P_1$ to $P_2$, 
   and normalized vs the absolute distance between $P_2$ and $P_1$.
   Therefore
   $$
   P_{a,\,b}  = P\left( {t_{\,0}  \pm \frac{{L/2}}
   {{\left| {P_{\,2}  - P_{\,1} } \right|}}} \right)
   $$